Why am i walking according the world's vector instead my own vector?
(Using DeepL)
I messed up my code and upon trying to redo it this bug raised. I'm new on Godot 4 and i couldn't find why this happens, everything i tried just ended up making things worse... I believe the issue is on "Movement" section but i don't know how to fix it. (Just in case i pasted all the code)
extends CharacterBody3D

# Player Nodes.
@onready var neck = $Neck
@onready var head = $Neck/Head
@onready var eyes = $Neck/Head/Eyes
@onready var player_camera = $Neck/Head/Eyes/PlayerCamera

# Speed Variables.
var current_speed = 0.0
var backward_speed = 0.0
const WALK_SPEED = 2.5
const SPRINT_SPEED = 5.0
const STEALTH_SPEED = 1.2

# States.
var walking = false
var sprinting = false
var stealthing = false

# Moving Variables.
var stealth_depth = -0.07
var lerp_speed = 10.0
var gravity = 9.8

# Input Variables.
var direction = Vector3.ZERO
const MOUSE_SENSITIVITY = 0.004

# Head Bob Variables.
var current_head_bob = 0.0
const HEAD_BOB_FREQUENCY = 0.0
const HEAD_BOB_AMPLITUDE = 0.0

func _ready():
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)

func _process(_delta):
    
    # Quit.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("quit"):
        get_tree().quit()

func _unhandled_input(event):
    
    # Camera Movement.
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        head.rotate_y(-event.relative.x * MOUSE_SENSITIVITY)
        player_camera.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * MOUSE_SENSITIVITY)
        player_camera.rotation.x = clamp(player_camera.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-90), deg_to_rad(90))

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    # Movement Input.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "forward", "backward")
    
    # Head Bob.
    current_head_bob += delta * velocity.length() * float(is_on_floor())
    player_camera.transform.origin = _headbob(current_head_bob)
    
    # Backward Walk.
    if Input.is_action_pressed("backward"):
        backward_speed = 1.0
    else:
        backward_speed = 0.0
    
    # Stealth.
    if Input.is_action_pressed("stealth"):
        current_speed = lerp(current_speed, STEALTH_SPEED - backward_speed, delta * lerp_speed)
        head.position.y = lerp(head.position.y, 1.5 + stealth_depth, delta * lerp_speed)
        var _walking = false
        var _sprinting = false
        var _stealthing = true
    else: 
        head.position.y = lerp(head.position.y, 1.5, delta * lerp_speed)
        
        # Sprint.
        if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
            current_speed = lerp(current_speed, SPRINT_SPEED - backward_speed, delta * lerp_speed)
            var _walking = false
            var _sprinting = true
            var _stealthing = false
        else:
            
            # Walk.
            current_speed = lerp(current_speed, WALK_SPEED - backward_speed, delta * lerp_speed)
            var _walking = true
            var _sprinting = false
            var _stealthing = false
    
    # Gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta
    
    # Movement.
    if is_on_floor():
        direction = lerp(direction, (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized(), delta * lerp_speed)
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * current_speed
        velocity.z = direction.z * current_speed
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0.0, current_speed)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0.0, current_speed)
    
    move_and_slide()

func _headbob(time) -> Vector3:
    var pos = Vector3.ZERO
    pos.y = sin(time * HEAD_BOB_FREQUENCY) * HEAD_BOB_AMPLITUDE
    pos.x = cos(time * HEAD_BOB_FREQUENCY / 2) * HEAD_BOB_AMPLITUDE
    return pos


Original code >>> https://github.com/LegionGames/FirstPersonController/blob/main/Scripts/Player.gd
I've tried to redo the code little by little as the original one, and as i said i've discovered the issue is on Movement section, but i don't what is causing it and how to fix. I've already asked a AI but it didn't answer anything. (Sorry the trouble)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A CharacterBody3D likewise the CharacterBody2D using move_and_slide will apply the movement transformation on world position.
If you need, you can read both ways position either on local and world transforms.
If you need to move based on some platform or another body:

Check contact with the platform.
Set velocity += platform velocity every physics frame.

